# Shell script to delete complete block itself if a string is found within the block

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file contains the data like below.

```
server {
  listen 50;
  proxy_pass xyz:50;
  hivinu
```

So i want to delete the upper and lower lines lines by passing the string as xyz: Can someone please give me the solution? I tried using sed but i can delete the lines below one (loop) only. But i am not sure how to delete the upper lines using sed or awk.

I tried the command sed -ie '/xyz:/,+1d' by passing xyz string to delete the below line in the file. –

I need the output once i pass the string xyz to file it should delete the complete lines of code and get the empty in the file.

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Could you please try like `awk '!/xyz/'   Input_file` OR `sed '/xyz/d'  Input_file` and let me know?

Comment: I tried but passing both commands will delete same line only. It won't delete the upper and lower lines.

Comment: Even grep command do the same operation.

Comment: @KandikuppaVinod, Can you please post expected sample output in your question, like you added your efforts. Do you want to delete whole block(Like what Ed sir mentioned here),please do confirm, since I added an answer but that doesn't remove complete block that only removes 1 line above `xyz` and 1 line after `xyz` only,please be clear here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, reading Input_file 2 times here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/xyz/){
    line_number=FNR
    nextfile
  }
  next
}
FNR<(line_number-2) || FNR>(line_number+1)
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                          ##Starting awk code from here.
FNR==NR{                                       ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE for first time Input_file is being read.
  if($0~/xyz/){                                ##Checking condition if a line contains string xyz then do following.
    line_number=FNR                            ##Assigning current line number to variable line_number here.
    nextfile                                   ##nextfile will STOP reading Input_file first time(GNU awk special).
  }
  next                                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                              ##Closing BLOCK for first time Input_file.
FNR<(line_number-1) || FNR>(line_number+1)     ##Cheking condition if current line number is lesser than line_number-1 AND greater than line_number+1 then print current line.
'  Input_file  Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```